# Whats is the unique string in analytics report URL?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, google-analytics-api

I need to open custom dimensions report from my website which will open google analytics. To open exact report i need to know analytics endpoint and its parameters.

```
https://analytics.google.com/analytics/web/#/report/visitors-custom-variables/xxxx090493w198642760p19323xxxx/_u.date00=20191101&_u.date01=20191214&explorer-graphOptions.primaryConcept=analytics.newVisits&explorer-table.secSegmentId=analytics.customDimension1&explorer-table.plotKeys=%5B%5D/
```

What is `xxxx090493w198642760p19323xxxx` string in url and where i can find it? This seems unique based on account.

Answer (score 0):

It is composed by:

**axxx090493**w198642760p19323xxxx --> a is for account id

axxx090493**w198642760**p19323xxxx --> w is for web property id

axxx090493w198642760**p19323xxxx** --> p is for profile id (view)